# Configure SSL between tomcat and apache http server

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

We have a security requirement to configure SSL between tomcat and apache http server. I am using mod_jk for connection between httpd and tomcat servers.

I couldn't find the correct document which explains my situation. If anyone knows, pl. help me.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you need to use the HTTP protocol instead of AJP.

HTTP supports encrypted communications (i.e. HTTPS), but AJP does not.  If you want to stick with AJP, you'd need to use encryption at a lower level, like a VPN or encrypted tunnel, and then route your AJP traffic over the encrypted network.

If you switch to HTTP, you can use HTTPD, mod_proxy and mod_ssl to encrypt connections between HTTPD & Tomcat.  The standard documentation on this is pretty good.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine

Comment: Hi Dan, I was doing further research and found https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ssl-howto.html#s4. It says "only ajp13 can forward SSL information to Tomcat".

Comment: First, that documentation you're referring to is really, really old.  It's referencing Tomcat 3.3, which is ancient.  Look at something more recent next time.  Second, it's not talking about the same thing.  It's talking about AJP's ability to forward SSL information which was gathered on the web server to Tomcat.  This allows the web server to terminate SSL, send the request to Tomcat via AJP and have Tomcat know that the request came in via SSL.  This helps applications to properly generate content like URLs.  It is absolutely not saying that AJP requests can be sent over SSL.